# Sign XML document with .jks compatiblae key store

Tags: x509, jks

I am signing saml Response and assertion with x509 certificate. The response is posted to a java app, which throws error Signature length not correct…". I am asked to make sure that the xml doc is signed with certificate in JKS format and not pkcs12.

Is there a way to sign xml document in jks format in c# and then post the saml response to java app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a XML document signed in JKS format. These are apples and oranges.

XML digital signatures are specified in XMLDsig standard (assuming that you use XML digital signatures). http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/

When you sign something you use the private key of an asymmetric key pair, probably an RSA key pair. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29

When you verify the signature you use the public key, commonly wrapped in an X.509 Certificate. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate

JKS and PKCS#12 are two different formats for storing the private key and the certificate in a container, encrypted using a password (since the private key is supposed to be private you want to protect it using a password).

When you sign an XML document you open the JKS/P12 keystore and use the private key to sign, and optionally include the certificate for easier verification for the recipient.
The private key and the certificate are *identical* in both cases, i.e. it does not matter if you use JKS or P12, the XML signature is bit for bit identical.

Probably you are sending both the XML document *and* the PKCS12 keystore to the recipient, and the recipient is unable to open PKCS12 keystore properly?

Java can open both JKS and PKCS12 with no problems at all, most likely your problem is related to something else than JKS vs PKCS12.

I do not know if C# can read and/or write JKS files (JKS == Java Key Store)